# Ignore first value in an array

Tags: php, arrays, fft

I have a range of fourier transform values in php as shown below.

```
[8974,398.22605659378,340.40931712583,224.61805748557,224.21476160103,531.02102311671,348.09311299013,74.373164045484,440.15451832283,379.54095616825,801.05398080895,184.15175862698,539.59590498835,114.82864261836,595.84662567888,488.12623039438,370,488.12623039438,595.84662567888,114.82864261836,539.59590498835,184.15175862698,801.05398080895,379.54095616825,440.15451832283,74.373164045484,348.09311299013,531.02102311671,224.21476160103,224.61805748557,340.40931712582,398.22605659378]
```

How do I actually ignore/delete away the first value in this case "8974" in php language?

Comment: after ignoring the `0th` index what do you intend to do next?

Comment: Use array_shift: http://be2.php.net/array_shift

Comment: You can use `array_shift`

Answer (score 0):

#### Ignore it

Create a temporary array from the first by skipping the first element:

```
foreach (array_slice($arr, 1) as $xyz) {
   /// ...
}
```

Or, without creating a temporary array:

```
reset($arr); next($arr); // reset and skip first element
while (list($key, $value) = each($arr)) {
    echo $value;
}
```

#### Modify it

Modify the array in place by shifting the first item off:

```
array_shift($arr);
// do whatever you want
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_shift();`

**Like**

```
    $array=array(8974,398.22605659378,340.40931712583,224.61805748557,224.21476160103,531.02102311671,348.09311299013,74.373164045484,440.15451832283,379.54095616825,801.05398080895,184.15175862698,539.59590498835,114.82864261836,595.84662567888,488.12623039438,370,488.12623039438,595.84662567888,114.82864261836,539.59590498835,184.15175862698,801.05398080895,379.54095616825,440.15451832283,74.373164045484,348.09311299013,531.02102311671,224.21476160103,224.61805748557,340.40931712582,398.22605659378);
array_shift($array);
print_r($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [array_shift](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php)

ie:

```
 $myArray = array(8974,398.22605659378,340.40931712583,224.61805748557,224.21476160103,531.02102311671,348.09311299013,74.373164045484,440.15451832283,379.54095616825,801.05398080895,184.15175862698,539.59590498835,114.82864261836,595.84662567888,488.12623039438,370,488.12623039438,595.84662567888,114.82864261836,539.59590498835,184.15175862698,801.05398080895,379.54095616825,440.15451832283,74.373164045484,348.09311299013,531.02102311671,224.21476160103,224.61805748557,340.40931712582,398.22605659378);
 array_shift($myArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily `unset` first element to Delete it:

```
unset($array[0]);
```